# How to handle? Error: Process.send_after() on server shutdown

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this GenServer that fires every time I create a particular object in my database.

#### GENSERVER:

```
defmodule Statcasters.Jobs.DisableQuestionPrediction do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{})
  end

  def init(question) do
    schedule_work(question)

    {:ok, question}
  end

  def handle_info(:work, question) do
    {:ok, question} = question

    Statcasters.Scheduler.disable_question_prediction(question)
    {:noreply, question}
  end

  defp schedule_work(question) do
    {:ok, question} = question
    schedule = Timex.diff(DateTime.utc_now, question.game_time, :milliseconds)

    Process.send_after(self(), :work, schedule)
  end
end
```

Basically I'm scheduling a function to run in the future. This function could be timed to run 1 hour or 12 hours in the future, but I realized that if the server shutdown for whatever reason then potentially the timing of this function is now off which ruins the entire point of the process.

How can I handle an error like that with Elixir? Does GenServer still keep the timer running even if the server is down?

Comment: Persist the `Time` of the next scheduled run somewhere (e.g. in `DETS`,) and check the storage inside `init` callback. I [handle this exact situation](https://github.com/am-kantox/tarearbol/blob/master/lib/tarearbol/cron.ex#L11) in [`Tarearbol`](https://github.com/am-kantox/tarearbol/) package.

Comment: Interesting. So the init callback will be called again when the server is back up?

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:init/1

Comment: I realized that this entire use case really didn't make sense for GenServer, I ended up moving this to Exq. Mainly because it handles the server crash because of Redis.

Comment: I doubt I understand how Redis is better than DETS, but ok.

Comment: Not at all saying that Redis is better than DETS at all. You actually introduced me to DETS I think it's a super powerful tool. But after fighting with it for a bit the Exq route seemed to fit this particular situation.